# Promise.all typscript does not make async call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise, angular-promise

I am trying to make a no. of async API calls and want to handle in Promise.all after all are returned and resolved.

```
if(this.selectedDomains.length > 0) {
      for(let i=0; i<this.selectedDomains.length; i++){
        promises.push(

          this.policyService.exportPolicies(this.selectedDomains[i].id, this.config['data'].policies)


        );

      }

      //wait for all exportPolicies calls to finish
      Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        console.log("ALL resolved !!");
          let successMsg = this.translate.instant("policy.resources.export_policy_success",
            [this.config['data'].policies.length, this.selectedDomains.length]);
          this.messageHelperService.showSuccess({hide: true, message: successMsg});
        }
      ).catch(function () {
      });
    }
```

Here **this.policyService.exportPolicies** is an async API call but it is never executed & I see  the console msg of **ALL resolved !!**

How can we make Promise.all resolved after all the async API calls in the **promises** array is resolved ?

API call details:

```
export class PolicyService {

  constructor ( private baseService : BaseService ) {
  }
  exportPolicies(domainId, policyIds) : Observable<import("@angular/common/http").HttpEvent<any[]>>{
    let url = COMMON.LEGACY_API_PATH + `policy/exportPolicy/${domainId}`;
    return this.baseService.postData(url, policyIds);
  }
```

```
export declare class BaseService {
    private http;
    constructor(http: HttpClient);
    handleError<T>(operation?: string, result?: T): (error: any) => Observable<T>;
    log(message: string, response: object): void;
    deleteData(url: string, data?: any): Observable<import("@angular/common/http").HttpEvent<any[]>>;
    getData(url: string): Observable<any[]>;
    postData(url: string, data?: any, params?: any): Observable<import("@angular/common/http").HttpEvent<any[]>>;
    putData(url: string, data?: any, params?: any): Observable<import("@angular/common/http").HttpEvent<any[]>>;
    patchData(url: string, data?: any, params?: any): Observable<import("@angular/common/http").HttpEvent<any[]>>;
    headData(url: string): Observable<any[]>;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<BaseService, never>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I see it correctly, `exportPolicies` returns an `Observable`. By calling `promises.push(this.policyService.exportPolicies(...))`, you add an `Observable` to your array called `promises`. Now `Promise.all` does not know how to handle an `Observable`, and simply doesn't execute it, but just returns the observable itself.

To solve it, you can simply convert the `Observable` to a `Promise`:

```
promises.push(this.policyService.exportPolicies(...)).toPromise();
```

You could avoid this problem altogether by properly typing `promises`, e.g. by declaring it as `const promises: Promise<MyType>[] = []`. Then your TypeScript compiler would already have complained before even executing :-).

Answer (score 0):

Either convert your Observables to Promises and use `Promise.all`, or use the equivalent of `Promise.all` for Observables: [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)